How to create the `c` argument specifiers in Expl3?
When I use the l3coffin modules, I confranted the usage of the command \coffin_reset_poles:N.

Surprisingly, it didn't provide the c argument specifiers. In the following MWE, I need to use \my_coffin_reset:n {l_tmpA_coffin} instead of \coffin_reset_poles:N \l_tmpA_coffin for the reason of better encapsulation.
How can I use the command cs:generate_variant or exp_args here?
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%% ---- error with \cs_generate_variant:Nn
% \cs_new:Nn \my_coffin_reset:n % <coffin>
% {
%     \cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_coffin_reset:n {c}
%     \coffin_reset_poles:c \coffin_reset_poles:N {\l_tmp#1_coffin}
% }
\coffin_new:c {l_tmpA_coffin}
\hcoffin_set:cn {l_tmpA_coffin} {\scalebox{6}{tmp\\tmp}}
\coffin_set_horizontal_pole:cnn {l_tmpA_coffin} {\tmpp} {10pt}

\coffin_display_handles:cn {l_tmpA_coffin} {magenta}
\coffin_reset_poles:N \l_tmpA_coffin %hope to use \my_coffin_reset:n {l_tmpA_coffin}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

Another problem is that: why most other expl3 command provided the c variant at the same time when N is provided EXCEPT the \coffin_reset_poles:N?

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coffin_reset_poles:N {c} outside from a definition. I don't know why it is missing, make a feature request.

Actuall it does, tks!  For learning, I just wonder if it can achieve with exp_args? (newbees to macros expansion)

@Explorer the \exp... module is the underlying code but the recommendation for anything you use more than once is to use generate_variant. By design if the variant gets added by default, it will be silently ignored and won't duplicate or give an wlready-defined error.

You just add
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coffin_reset_poles:N {c}

at the outer level (between \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff, of course).
Why isn't the variant predefined? Likely because nobody asked for it.
Is there any problem with using \cs_generate_variant:Nn? Not at all. This function is designed so that, if the variant already exists, it does nothing except wasting a few nanoseconds in processing time.
Can you use \exp_args:Nc? Yes. If you run
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coffin_reset_poles:N {c}
\cs_show:N \coffin_reset_poles:c

you will see
> \coffin_reset_poles:c=\protected\long macro:->\exp_args:Nc \coffin_reset_poles:N .

Why using the variant then? Because it provides clearer code. A one-off \exp_args:N... usage isn't a problem. If you need the variant more than a couple of time, generate it.
